# Trigger not working:

Tags: mysql, triggers

I created trigger on table PENDING. Pending table has 3 columns - uniqueId , duration and maxDuration. I have another table COUNT with 2 columns - req_id, total

Here is my trigger--

```
CREATE TRIGGER plus3second BEFORE INSERT
ON PENDING
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE req_id varchar(25);
DECLARE total int(11);
DECLARE duration int(2);

SET req_id = SUBSTR(new.uniqueId, 1, 14);

Select total into total from COUNT where req_id = 'req_id';

IF total > 100 THEN

 SET duration = new.duration + 3;

  IF duration < new.maxDuration Then
     SET new.duration = duration;
  END IF;


END IF;


END
```

Trigger created successfully. I fired these queries on COUNT and PENDING-

```
insert into COUNT values ('77711422099653',200);
insert into PENDING (uniqueId, duration, maxDuration) values ('77711422099653919893277163', 3, 20);
```

But trigger not working ...Where is the problem ?

Comment: Haven't checked if it solves your problem, but as a general rule: Never name a variable same as anything else you're using, like columns or tables or keywords.

Comment: @tombom - i tried the same but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with this trigger definition(with less conflicting names):

```
CREATE TRIGGER plus3second
   BEFORE INSERT
   ON PENDING
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   DECLARE tReqID     varchar(25);
   DECLARE tTotal      int(11);
   DECLARE tDuration   int(2);

   SET tReqID = SUBSTR(new.uniqueId, 1, 14);

   SELECT total
     INTO tTotal
     FROM COUNT
    WHERE req_id = tReqID;

   IF tTotal > 100
   THEN
      SET tDuration = new.duration + 3;

      IF tDuration < new.maxDuration
      THEN
         SET new.duration = tDuration;
      END IF;
   END IF;
END
```